# getting records from list based on category

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Query:

```
List<vwBookTitleKitsSummary> theseKits = (from k in _dataContext.vwBookTitleKitsSummaries
                                                      where k.DateKitEnds > DateTime.Now && k.DateKitStarts <= DateTime.Now && k.IsDeleted == false 
                                                      orderby k.KitOrder, k.KitCode descending
                                                      select k).ToList();
```

thesekits got 6 results like below (the highlighted ones):

[image]

**I want a query that returns one item from each category
for example I want the records K1503, T1503**
i.e.

I want first record that start with **K** and first record that start with **T**

I tried like following:

```
List<vwBookTitleKitsSummary> theseKits = (from k in _dataContext.vwBookTitleKitsSummaries
                                                      where k.DateKitEnds > DateTime.Now && k.DateKitStarts <= DateTime.Now && k.IsDeleted == false && (k.KitCode.StartsWith("K"))
                                                      orderby k.KitOrder, k.KitCode descending
                                                      select k).Take(1).ToList();

List<vwBookTitleKitsSummary> qry = (from k in _dataContext.vwBookTitleKitsSummaries
                           where k.DateKitEnds > DateTime.Now && k.DateKitStarts <= DateTime.Now && k.IsDeleted == false && (k.KitCode.StartsWith("T"))
                           orderby k.KitOrder, k.KitCode descending
                           select k).Take(1).ToList();
theseKits.AddRange(qry);
```

This will return records with KitCode - **K1503, T1503**

Instead of writing two queries and using AddRange can that be done in one query, any help please.

Comment: try adding OR condition in your first query

Comment: adding (k.KitCode.StartsWith("K") || k.KitCode.StartsWith("T") with Take(2) results with K1503,K1502. I need one from each  KitCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you 1 record per category, for all starting letters in your category.

```
List<vwBookTitleKitsSummary> firstCategoryTheseKits = _dataContext
     .vwBookTitleKitsSummaries.Where(k => k.DateKitEnds > DateTime.Now 
      && k.DateKitStarts <= DateTime.Now && k.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(k => k.KitOrder)
     .ThenByDescending(k => k.KitCode).GroupBy(k => k.KitCode[0]).Select(grps => grps.First)
     .ToList();
```

If you want only for T or K, you can add a where condition as follows:

```
List<vwBookTitleKitsSummary> firstCategoryTheseKits = _dataContext
     .vwBookTitleKitsSummaries.Where(k => k.DateKitEnds > DateTime.Now 
     && k.DateKitStarts <= DateTime.Now && k.IsDeleted == false 
     && (k.KitCode[0] == 'T' || k.KitCode[0] == 'K')).OrderBy(k => k.KitOrder)
     .ThenByDescending(k => k.KitCode).GroupBy(k => k.KitCode[0])
     .Select(grps => grps.First).ToList();
```

Sorry my query is in concise notation, instead of your query notation.

Comment: The first one works, thank you, but If I want to skip the first in each category? For example I want everything but not T1503, K1503 in above 6 results. Please.

Comment: in that case you can add this check, which basically selects only groups with more than 1 record and skips over the first record: GroupBy(k => k.KitCode[0]).Where(grps => grps.Count() > 1).Select(grps => grps.Skip(1).First())

Comment: It is giving second record from each category. For example I want to exclude T1503,K1503 but I want T1502,T1501,K1502,K1501. grps.Skip(1).First() always returns one, I want something like grps.Skip(1).All(). Please help.

Comment: ohh. in that case just do SelectMany(grps => grps.Skip(1)).ToList()  the SelectMany flattens out the list..

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the first character and take the first item of each group:

```
from k in _dataContext.vwBookTitleKitsSummaries
where k.DateKitEnds > DateTime.Now && k.DateKitStarts <= DateTime.Now
   && k.IsDeleted == false 
orderby k.KitOrder, k.KitCode descending
group k by k.KitCode.SubString(0,1) into grp
select new { grp.Key, k = grp.FirstOrDefault() }
```

Or just `select grp.FirstOrDefault()` if you like.